# How to speed up Magento2's Admin/Backend?

Tags: magento2, admin, performance

How to speed up Magento2's Admin/Backend?

I have tried http://suyati.com/speed-up-magento-admin-backend/ with no luck.

Comment: have you tried http://www.venustheme.com/speed-up-magento-2/ this? you can also check your site performance from this online tool https://gtmetrix.com/

Comment: my frontend working better but admin panel takes so much time to load, upload, save, everything takes so much time

Comment: Check this https://suyati.com/blog/speed-up-magento-admin-backend/

Answer (score 1):

are you in production mode? in developer and default mode all static files are processed through a php script which is pretty slow.

If not in production mode the Less Processing also takes pretty much time.

All other possibilities to speed up the backend would be having all caches enabled and using a faster cache backen (like redis)

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/redis/config-redis.html

Answer (score 1):

Your frontend is faster than backend because it most probably uses full page cache.

Trick number #1 is to switch to **production mode**.

If you need to stay in developer mode then here are 3 tips:

1. **Disable CSS & JS merge / bundle / minify**. You can do so at *Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Javascript Settings and CSS Settings*
2. **Move to PHP7**
3. **Increase php memory limit to at least 2G**. Get mode CPU power. Magento 2 is a resource hungry beast

Taken from the original article [Speed up Magento 2 and 1](https://www.goivvy.com/blog/speed-up-magento).